# importing Android project from Bitbucket to the IntelliJ IDEA plugin with id com.android.application not found

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I'm attempting clone the project from the Bitbucket but I've got this error :

[image]

I've downloaded gradle plugin 2.2.1 - http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

And when project importing, I use the path to the gradle 2.2.1, nevertheless problem still remains.

Besides, when I'm using customizable gradle wrapper, not from local - got the same problem.

What can be the solution ?

Comment: Why don't you use Android Studio?

Comment: I've got the same error in the Android Studio. Some problem with the Gradle I guess

Comment: Which version of AS do you use? The `com.android.application` plugin was interduced in AS 0.6 I think.

Comment: I've got 0.8.14 version and gradle 2.2.1

Comment: Try updating to AS 1.0.0-RC2.

Comment: intalled AS 1.0.0-RC2 and got the same result